# imported module randomly set to None

Tags: python, spyder

I have a very strange problem with a script which has the following structure:

```
import os

# ... some functions

def function_one():

    ...

def function_two():

    if os.path.isdir(...):
```

The last statement sometimes fails with `NoneType has no attribute 'path'`, and accidently I discovered that the modfied version of `function_two`

```
def function_two():
    if os is None:
        print function_one
```

prints `None`. So not only `os` is `None` but `function_one` is `None` too.

I want to reproduce the error but do not know at all where to look for a reason, I have no global variables and I do not modify `sys.modules`.

Does anybody have an idea how `os` can become `None` at all ? I was not able to simulate this without using global variables with names `os` and `function_one`...

Comment: Yep, globals are pretty much the only way this could happen.  FWIW, If another module _imports_ this module, they could also monkey-patch its globals to set `os` and `function_one` to `None`...

Comment: You get this effect when CPython shuts down: it replaces globals with None for some (mostly historical) reason.  Are the functions called from `__del__` methods that run when the interpreter shuts down?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Is there code assigning `None` to those names? Can you show more code?

Answer (score 0):

If you had another module in your PYTHONPATH named os, it could be getting imported instead.  As people mentioned in comments, another module may also be monkey-patching the os module, either in sys.modules or by importing your module.